# milliseconds format to parse a datetime?

Tags: datetime, milliseconds, datetime-parsing, google-bigquery

I need to `parse` a `datetime` contains **milliseconds** for matching the max value in a field containing this datetimes.

For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%u','2017-08-18 16:04:40.890')
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: Convert to milliseconds, suddendly `MAX()`.

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT date
  FROM UNNEST([
    DATETIME '2017-08-18 16:04:40.890',
    DATETIME '2017-07-27 11:09:10.347',
    DATETIME '2017-08-22 13:17:34.727',
    DATETIME '2017-08-22 13:17:34.737']) AS date
)
SELECT
  MAX(CAST(date AS DATETIME))
FROM Input;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S','2017-08-18 16:04:40.890')
```

Comment: How to parse to timestamp from a timestamp string with value of milliseconds separated by colon instead of dot? Eg: "2017-08-18 16:04:40:890" I have tried with ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E3S') but its giving me error. @Mikhail Berlyant